# Get part of matched value with regex

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to get part of a string.

Used this expression:

```
@"<a .*href=""(?<Url>(.*))(?="")"""
```

Example data to match:

```
var input = @"<html lang=""en"">
    <head>
        <link href=""http://www.somepage.com/c/main.css"" rel=""stylesheet"" type=""text/css"" />

        <link rel=""canonical"" href=""http://www.somepage.com"" />
        <script src=""http://www.somepage.com/professional/bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js"" type=""text/javascript""></script>
    </head>
        <body>
            <header>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <a aria-haspopup=""true"" href=""http://www.somepage.com/someotherpage""><img src=""http://www.somepage.com/i/sprite/logo.png"" alt=page"" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
        </body>
    </html>"
```

For now I was able to get this value:

```
http://www.somepage.com/someotherpage\"><img src=""http://www.somepage.com/i/sprite/logo.png"" alt=page"" /></a>
```

with this code:

```
var regexPattern = new Regex(PATTERN, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var matches = regexPattern.Matches(httpResult);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    // here I'm getting this value 
    var extractedValue = match.Groups["Url"].Value; // it's value is http://www.somepage.com/someotherpage\"><img src=""http://www.somepage.com/i/sprite/logo.png"" alt=page"" /></a>
}
```

What I want to get under `match.Groups["Url"].Value` is simple `http://www.somepage.com/someotherpage` without anything after `href` `attribute` value.

Is it possible to get only that part of match without using `Substring` on `extractedValue`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there. Just one minor change in your regex to not allow quotes in the matching set.

```
<a .*href=""(?<Url>([^"]*))(?="")""
                  //^^^^ This is what i changed.
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this would work. Unfortunately I don't have time to test it now:

```
"<a[^>]*href=\"(?<Url>([^\"]+))\"[^>]*>"
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
<a .*href=""(?<Url>(.+?))(?="")""
```

The problem was that in (.*) the * is greedy. +? ["Matches the previous element one or more times, but as few times as possible"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx#quantifiers) so it will stop at the first quotation mark. For more information about greediness in regular expressions, you can check out [Regex Tutorial - Repetition with Star and Plus](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern instead, much less backtracking when not using the `.*` meme (faster processing). Also the pattern uses `\x22` as `"` for easier manipulation of the pattern, because it avoids C# literal confusion issue.

```
Regex.Matches(input, @"<a.+href=\x22(?<Url>[^\x22]+).+/a>")
     .OfType<Match>()
     .Select (mt => mt.Groups["Url"].Value);
     // Result = http://www.somepage.com/someotherpage
```